# jQuery: Button submits form only after two clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am making a form validation function, and if there are no empty input's the button takes two clicks to work correctly.

This is my function:

```
function validate(root, animation, error) {
    $('.button').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        var isEmpty    = false,
            root       = $(root),
            animation  = animation ? animation : 'animation animation-shake',
            error      = error ? error : 'error';

        root.find('form').find('.required').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                isEmpty = true;
                root.addClass(animation);
                $('.required.error:first').focus();
                $(this).addClass(error).on('keydown', function() {
                    $(this).removeClass(error);
                    root.removeClass(animation);
                });
            }
        });

        if (isEmpty) return;
        $(this).unbind('click');
    });
}
```

The code that calls the function:

```
validate('#login-box .box');
```

Any ideas would be great, also suggestions about how to shorten/improve the code.

Comment: What is the intended behaviour?

Comment: Set `event.preventDefault()` inside `if (isEmpty){...}` block. No need of return statement nor to unbind click event

Comment: `error = error || 'error';` does the same job as `error      = error ? error : 'error';`

Comment: you probably need to take the onkeyup hander out of the onclick handler.. make a jsfiddle

Comment: @tewathia Thank you for the suggestion, implemented.

Comment: @A.Wolff This worked like a charm, a very smart solution. Will you post this as an answer so I can close my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should be:

```
function validate(root, animation, error) {
    $('.button').on('click', function(event) {
        /* event.preventDefault();*/ //<< remove it
        var isEmpty    = false,
           /*...*/
        /*if (isEmpty) return;
          $(this).unbind('click');*/ //<< remove it

        // and set at handler bottom   
        if (isEmpty) event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Only prevent submit behaviour when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding click event to button inside validate function that's why it requires 2 clicks
First click binds click event then second click triggers code inside it.
Remove on click event from code.

Comment: Even before this was a function, the result was the same.

Comment: Where does it say that `validate(..)` is being called from a button click?

Comment: @freedomn-m.  I think $('.button').click() is added inside validate function... please check if I'm not wrong

Comment: Yes, but you stated "first click binds click event" - ie that `validate` is called *from* a click event, for which there is no evidence (it's more likely called from `$()`)

Comment: @freedomn-m ohh... sorry for my english